# Java Nio ByteBuffer truncate unicode characters when buffer reaches its bound

Tags: java, unicode, io, nio, filereader

I was writing a function in java that can read file and get its content to String:

```java
public static String ReadFromFile(String fileLocation) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = null;
    FileChannel fileChannel = null;
    try {
        randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(fileLocation, "r");
        fileChannel = randomAccessFile.getChannel();
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(10);
        CharBuffer charBuffer = null;
        int bytesRead = fileChannel.read(byteBuffer);
        while (bytesRead != -1) {
            byteBuffer.flip();
            charBuffer = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(byteBuffer);
            result.append(charBuffer.toString());
            byteBuffer.clear();
            bytesRead = fileChannel.read(byteBuffer);
        }
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fileChannel != null)
                fileChannel.close();
            if (randomAccessFile != null)
                randomAccessFile.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

From code above you can see that I set 'ByteBuffer.allocate' only 10 bytes on purpose to make things clearer.
Now I want to read a file named "test.txt" that contains unicode charaters in Chinese like this:

```
乐正绫我爱你乐正绫我爱你
```

Below is my test code for it:

```java
System.out.println(ReadFromFile("test.txt"));
```

**Expected Output in Console**

```
乐正绫我爱你乐正绫我爱你
```

**Actual Output in Console**

```
乐正绫���爱你��正绫我爱你
```

**Possible Reason**
ByteBuffer only allocated 10 bytes, thus unicode characters are truncated every 10 bytes.

**Attempt To Solve**
Increase ByteBuffer allocated bytes to 20, I got the result below:

```
乐正绫我爱你��正绫我爱你
```

**Not A Robust Solution**
Allocate ByteBuffer to a very huge number, like 102400, but it is not practical when it comes to very huge text files.

**Question**
How to solve this problem?

Comment: You're making this *way* to complicated. Even if you didn't know of the methods pointed out by the answer, you should have just opened a `FileReader` with the correct encoding and looped over that with `read`. All this extra complication doesn't really buy you much. Or put differently: why do you think you need NIO for this at all?

Comment: Is there are reason you are specifically wanting/needing to do this with NIO, or are you just asking a hypothetical question out of curiosity, in which case your question is arguably off topic, and therefore liable to be closed.

Comment: I got that, Nio is not a must. It is okay if the problem can be solved, no matter what method to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, since you don't know how many bytes are used for each character in UTF-8 encoding, and you really don't want to rewrite that logic.

There's [Files.readString()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readString(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.charset.Charset)) in Java 11, for lower versions you can use [Files.readAllBytes()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)) e.g.

```
Path path = new File(fileLocation).toPath()
String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to correctly use [`CharsetDecoder.decodeLoop`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#decodeLoop(java.nio.ByteBuffer,java.nio.CharBuffer)) here until I realized that OP just wrote a very complex way of reading the entire file content as a `String` ...

Comment: Hey, I wonder if there are any similar ways to write String to file this easy, because I've written a very complicated WriteStringToFile method, too.

Comment: @Paper_Folding `java.net.FileWriter`.

Comment: @user207421 Solved with `java.nio.file.Files.writeString`